# Python: Searching for Unicode string in HTML with index/find returns wrong position

Tags: python, html

I am trying to parse the number of results from the HTML code returned from a search query, however when I use find/index() it seems to return the wrong position. The string I am searching for has an accent, so I try searching for it in Unicode form.

A snippet of the HTML code being parsed:

```
<div id="WPaging_total">
  Aproximádamente 37 resultados.
</div>
```

and I search for it like this:

```
str_start = html.index(u'Aproxim\xe1damente ')
str_end = html.find(' resultados', str_start + 16)#len('Aproxim\xe1damente ')==16
print html[str_start+16:str_end] #works by changing 16 to 24
```

The print statement returns:

```
damente 37
```

When the expected result is:

```
37
```

It seems str_start isn't starting at the beginning of the string I am searching for, instead 8 positions back.

```
print html[str_start:str_start+5]
```

Outputs:

```
l">
```

The problem is hard to replicate though because it doesn't happen when using the code snippet, only when searching inside the entire HTML string. I could simply change str_start+16 to str_start+24 to get it working as intended, however that doesn't help me understand the problem. Is it a Unicode issue? Hopefully someone can shed some light on the issue.

Thank you.

**LINK:**
http://guiasamarillas.com.mx/buscador/?actividad=Chedraui&localidad=&id_page=1

**SAMPLE CODE**:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url = 'http://guiasamarillas.com.mx/buscador/?actividad=Chedraui&localidad=&id_page=1'
post = None
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2)'}          
req = Request(url, post, headers)
conn = urlopen(req)

html = conn.read()

str_start = html.index(u'Aproxim\xe1damente ')
str_end = html.find(' resultados', str_start + 16)
print html[str_start+16:str_end]
```

Comment: 'html' is what? A unicode string? An utf-8 encoded string?

Comment: html is type str, returned by urllib2 using Request/open. I tried unicode(html, 'utf-8'), but I got the exact same results.

Comment: You need to provide more detail on what `s` and `html` are.  Maybe provide the link, etc. so we can pull it ourselves.

Comment: At a guess - and I suspect user1833746 is thinking along the same lines - I would speculate that this has something to do with the fact that the `str` type in Python 2.x represents a sequence of bytes, whereas the `unicode` type is a sequence of characters. Consequently any string encoded in such a way that some characters are represented by multiple bytes will appear longer than the number of characters it contains if you call `len()` on it. For example, `len(u'£'.encode('utf-8'))` returns `2`, as will `len('£')` if utf-8 is your default system encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem ultimately boils down to the fact that in Python 2.x, the `str` type represents a sequence of bytes while the `unicode` type represents a sequence of characters. Because one character can be encoded by multiple bytes, that means that the length of a `unicode`-type representation of a string may differ from the length of a `str`-type representation of the same string, and, in the same way, an index on a `unicode` representation of the string may point to a different part of the text than the same index on the `str` representation.

What's happening is that when you do `str_start = html.index(u'Aproxim\xe1damente ')`, Python automatically decodes the `html` variable, assuming that it is encoded in utf-8. (Well, actually, on my PC I simply get a `UnicodeDecodeError` when I try to execute that line. Some of our system settings relating to text encoding must be different.) Consequently, if `str_start` is n then that means that `u'Aproxim\xe1damente '` appears at the *nth character* of the HTML. However, when you use it as a slice index later to try and get content after the (n+16)th character, what you're actually getting is stuff after the *(n+16)th byte*, which in this case is not equivalent because earlier content of the page featured accented characters that take up 2 bytes when encoded in utf-8.

The best solution would be simply to convert the html to unicode when you receive it. This small modification to your sample code will do what you want with no errors or weird behaviour:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url = 'http://guiasamarillas.com.mx/buscador/?actividad=Chedraui&localidad=&id_page=1'
post = None
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2)'}          
req = Request(url, post, headers)
conn = urlopen(req)

html = conn.read().decode('utf-8')

str_start = html.index(u'Aproxim\xe1damente ')
str_end = html.find(' resultados', str_start + 16)
print html[str_start+16:str_end]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked perfectly! I had foolishly tried `unicode(html).encode('utf-8')` instead. Also, I apologize for not being able to up-vote your answer, I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: @LightOS Glad to have helped. :) As you may have already figured out, the line `unicode(html).encode('utf-8')` wouldn't have helped because on your machine it does effectively nothing - it decodes the utf-8 byte string into a unicode character string, and then re-encodes it. (On my machine, on the other hand, it attempts to do the decoding using the ascii codec and throws `UnicodeDecodeError`).

Comment: That worries me a little as I will need to run the script on other machines as well and the default system settings for text encoding could differentiate and cause trouble.

Comment: @LightOS Then simply be sure to specify the encoding when converting between type `str` and type `unicode`. In other words, never write `unicode(some_byte_string)` - instead write `some_byte_string.decode('utf-8')` or `unicode(some_byte_string, 'utf-8')`. Similarly, never write `str(some_unicode_string)`; instead write `some_unicode_string.encode('utf-8')`. Always being explicit about what codec you're using when converting between `str` and `unicode` in Python will save you from a world of nasty traps.

Comment: Cool, that's easy enough. Once again thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but if I'm guessing correctly that you're trying to grab from your HTML file the approximate number of results, you're probably better off as you have it using the `re` module for regular expressions.

```py
import re
re.search(ur'(?<=Aproxim\xe1damente )\d+', s).group(0)

# returns:
#   u'37'
```

Ultimately, your best bet is really a package like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`, but without more context I can't give you more specific help with those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could use the re module or other alternatives, but that still doesn't help me understand why using index/find isn't working.