# Unicode constructor will accept a unicode object, but ONLY if no kwargs are passed

Tags: python

example:

```
>>> uni = u'some text'
>>> print unicode(uni)
some text
>>> print unicode(uni, errors='ignore')
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 print unicode(uni, errors='ignore')
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

Why does this blow up only if I pass additional parameters to the constructor?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode): *"If `encoding` and/or `errors` are given, `unicode()` will decode the object which can either be an 8-bit string or a character buffer"*

Comment: Also, your test case only works if your unicode string is using only the ascii subset, otherwise you likely to get UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: @PauloScardine No, the characters used by the unicode string are entirely irrelevant to the behaviour of the above code. If it were a *byte* string, you would be right (e.g. `unicode('foo')` works but `unicode('£')` explodes on my system).

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0337a460f05b/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l14757),

```
static PyObject *
unicode_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyObject *x = NULL;
    static char *kwlist[] = {"object", "encoding", "errors", 0};
    char *encoding = NULL;
    char *errors = NULL;

    if (type != &PyUnicode_Type)
        return unicode_subtype_new(type, args, kwds);
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "|Oss:str",
                                     kwlist, &x, &encoding, &errors))
        return NULL;
    if (x == NULL)
        _Py_RETURN_UNICODE_EMPTY();
    if (encoding == NULL && errors == NULL)
        return PyObject_Str(x);
    else
        return PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject(x, encoding, errors);
}
```

notice that near the bottom,

```
if (encoding == NULL && errors == NULL)
    return PyObject_Str(x);
else
    return PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject(x, encoding, errors);
```

So when called without the `errors` parameter, `PyObject_Str(x)` is called, and this raises no TypeError. But when `error` and/or `encoding` is supplied, then `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject` is called, and now `x` must be an encoded string, not a unicode.

Comment: That's unfortunate, because a function that always returns a valid Unicode object no matter what you pass it would be really handy.

Comment: @MarkRansom And impossible (at least to create one that behaves usefully and without nasty traps), since the process of converting a byte string to a unicode string depends upon the encoding. You can have a default, but then you're still screwed when you pass a byte string that can't be decoded by that encoding.

Comment: @MarkRandom: Maybe so, but what I find really unfortunate is [functions that sometimes return `str` and sometimes `unicode`](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-does-lxml-sometimes-return-str-values-for-text-in-python-2). They are the ones that cause the problem in the first place.

Comment: @unutbu Absolutely. That 'feature' of `lxml` is pure evil.

Comment: It seems intuitively obvious that specifying the `errors` parameter might cause an exception when the first argument was a unicode string, since the errors parameter describes how to handle errors in the decoding process. If the first argument is a unicode string, there *is* no decoding process, so it makes no sense to specify how to handle errors during it. This rationale behind the behaviour seems worth noting in addition to the fact that it is specced - the behaviour as it stands is what I find least surprising.

Comment: @MarkAmery: `errors='ignore'` could be taken to mean ignore *all* errors, including the TypeError I'm committing right now :) So I'm not sure it is intuitively obvious.

Comment: @unutbu just FYI, I've gone ahead and added an additional answer that I think complements yours - mine quotes the documentation and makes an argument for why the behaviour is (in my view) the most reasonable thing the function can do.

Comment: @MarkAmery: If you know you have a `unicode`, there is absolutely no reason to call `unicode` on it. So you would only call `unicode` if you know you have a `str` or are uncertain if you have a `str` or `unicode`. You might well want to call `unicode(obj, errors='ignore')` which works on the `str` but fails on the `unicode`. That's unfortunate, because it seems the reason why the `unicode` function accept `unicode` objects is to allow you to deal with this uncertainty. The OP's question shows that the `unicode` function fails to allow the user to handle both `unicode` and `strs` seemlessly.

Comment: @MarkAmery: So it might be reasonable from the developer's point of view, but it makes life more difficult from the user's point of view. You have to either test the type of the object before calling `unicode`, or use `try..except`.

Comment: @unutbu Yeah, it's pretty inconvenient for dealing with the case where you have a mixture of unicode and str objects. I almost wanted to blame `lxml` for that case even existing, but actually I blame Python for its broken philosophy of letting you freely intermix unicode and byte strings (e.g. it lets you do `'foo' + u'bar'` or `'foo'.find(u'bar')`) when in my view these operations should be `TypeError`s for consistency with the language not letting you do stuff like `1+'1'` (and because mixing string types this way is horribly trap-prone but doesn't look like it to the naive eye).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663330/python-searching-for-unicode-string-in-html-with-index-find-returns-wrong-posit/) is a great illustration of why I think Python's liberal attitude towards its two string types is actually evil, and what it needs is to *more* willing to throw exceptions, be *less* tolerant of mixing the two types, and always force you to explicitly specify encodings when converting. If it had got that right in the first place, libraries like `lxml` wouldn't have created functions that returned `str` or `unicode` unpredictably. (Forgive my ranting.) :)

Comment: @MarkAmery: I wholeheartedly agree with you, and so does Python3. In Python3 no (builtin) function accepts both byte strings and unicode strings. There is no more silent, automatic conversion between the two. And lxml names and text are always unicode strings.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour [is documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode):

> #### `unicode(object[, encoding[, errors]])`
>
> If *encoding* and/or *errors* are given, `unicode()` will decode the object which can either be an 8-bit string or a character buffer using the codec for *encoding*.

The behaviour is also logical. To see this, note that *without* additional arguments,

```
unicode(some_unicode_string)
```

returns the unicode string completely unchanged, while

```
unicode(some_byte_string)
```

attempts to decode the byte string into a unicode string using the default system encoding.

In the latter case, the optional additional arguments make sense; the `encoding` argument tells the function which encoding to use to convert the byte string to a unicode one, and the `errors` argument tells it what to do if errors occur during the decoding process (i.e. if there are byte sequences that cannot be decoded using the given encoding).

However, when calling `unicode()` on a unicode string, there *is* no decoding process, so neither of the additional arguments would have any meaning. It is - I think - entirely reasonable and intuitive that Python handles meaningless arguments being provided by throwing an exception.